# BFS & DFS - Which vertex to start with?

Tags: algorithm, search

I've read pages and pages of information on BFS and DFS algorithms. What none of them say, is which vertex to choose first?

For instance, in this image, do the arrows mean you cannot traverse from c to b, but can traverse from b to c?

[image: search network]

Your help is much appreciated, friends.

Comment: The starting vertex is a parameter of the search. You specify it when you call the search, and the search only visits vertices reachable from the starting vertex.

Comment: Indeed, they don't say that because "breadth-first" and "depth-first" just refer to the order that you visit nodes.  The start node depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not a directed graph, it doesn't matter.
The graph you posted is a directed graph which means exactly what you've stated. You can go from a to b but not from b to a.

Regarding which node to choose in a directed graph, every node you'll choose can produce different result. Usually under these circumstances it's best to start from the root node if it's given.

Answer (score 5):

**[Breadth-first_search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)** and **[Depth-first_search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)** can be started with any source Vertex **S**.

**Which of the vertex to select as a source vertex?**-`Depends upon your requirement`.

**Example**:

1. If you want to find the *shortest path from Source S to all of the
   other vertex using BFS(for graph with all edges having same cost or unweighted graph)*.Then you should select **S** as source vertex.
2. If you want to find whether vertex **K** is reachable from vertex **S** or
   not, in this case too you have to start your BFS/DFS from source
   vertex S.
3. If you want to solve **Rat in a Maze** problem in which a rat starts from source **S** and has to reach destination using DFS, then again you have to start the DFS algorithm from Source **S**.

`In some Cases, We are free to choose  any vertex as a source vertex`.

**Example**:

1. While Finding Strongly Connected Component(SCC) of a directed graph,
   we start DFS by selecting any vertex as a Source Vertex.
2. While performing a Topological Sort of a Directed Acyclic Graph
   using DFS, again we are free to select any vertex as a Source Vertex.

*Thus, Which vertex to choose first is not fixed and depends upon the nature of the problem , we are solving with DFS and BFS.*

Comment: For topological sort, are we actually free to select any vertex as a source vertex?
I have no idea how it can be finished with DFS if the selected vertex has only incoming edges.

Comment: @cindy50633 Only incoming edges mean that the vertex has no unseen children and thus can be considered finished.

Answer (score 4):

`do the arrows mean you cannot traverse from c to b, but can traverse from b to c?`

This is a directed graph, Yes.

You don't need to specify which node to start with when you do DFS since you will iterate over all the nodes anyway.

The process of DFS is:

```
DFSmain(G):
     For v=1 to n: if v is not yet visited, do DFS(v).

DFS(v):
   mark v as visited. // entering node v
   for each unmarked out-neighbor w of v: do DFS(w).
   return. // exiting node v.
```

So it will  finally visit every node in the graph.
Similar rationale for BFS.